# Number of solutions to $\sin^2 x +2 \cos ^2 x +3 \sin x \cos x =0$

Tags: trigonometry

> What is for $0\le x<2\pi $, the number of solutions of the equation:
> $$
> \sin^2 x +2 \cos ^2 x +3 \sin x \cos x =0.
> $$

**My try:**

$\sin^2 x +2 \cos ^2 x +3 \sin x \cos x =0$
$\implies \tan ^2 x +3\tan x +2=0$
$\implies (\tan x +2)(\tan x +1)=0.$

Now $\tan x +1=0$ gives $x=\frac {3\pi}4, \frac {7\pi}4$.

But how to find $x$ from $\tan x +2=0$?
Please help. Thanks in advance
*Edited after Aaryan Patil's answer.

Comment: You can write it as $\pi - \arctan(2)$ and $2\pi - \arctan(2)$.

Comment: @MathLover then how do I guess that $\pi - \arctan 2$ and $2\pi - \arctan 2$ are between $0 $ and $2\pi$

Comment: your solution is $\tan x = - 2$ and $\tan x$ is negative in second and fourth quadrant. Note that $\arctan(2)$ will return a value between $[0, \pi/2] \ $.  So $\pi - \arctan(2)$ is in second quadrant and $2\pi - \arctan(2)$ is in fourth.

Comment: For solving tanx+2 = 0 , you need to go on Newton's method. I don't know are you aware by this method or not.

Comment: @MathLover good insight. (+1)

Comment: @MathLover one question. Why not $\arctan (2)$ will return value in 3rd quadrant?

Comment: Good question. I searched for something that would readily answer your question. See if this helps - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3247652/why-isnt-arctan-tan-x-x

Comment: @MathLover wow. Thanks (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have made a minor error when dividing the equation by $\cos^2(x)$. Your $\tan(x)$ has coefficient $3$ but it should be $2$.

\begin{align}
\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)} &= \frac{2\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} \\ &= 2\tan(x)
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: ...or was the $3$ coefficient intended?

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo from me. I've edited.

Comment: We can divide unless $x=\pi/2$.But if we do factorize without dividing by $\cos^2 x$ then also we will get the factor $(\sin x +2\cos x) $. Which will again cause problem. Isn't it?

Comment: According to the graph you provided there is no solution because it cuts $x$ axis nowhere. But no option shows that.

Comment: I will promptly update it. But your original method is perfectly alright. $tan(x)=-2$ does have solutions but you'll need to use inverse tan to find it and it comes out as a decimal answer.

Comment: But how can we calculate $\arctan (-2)$ without using calculator? Actually that was my question - 'how can we calculate the value of $x$ from $\tan x+2=0$?

Comment: Unfortunately I am still in the process of learning such things. Though I recall there to be some link with Taylor series expansion. You might need to ask others on that I guess. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Answer (score 0):

You can write as $$\sin^{2}x + \cos^{2}x + \cos^{2}x + 3 \sin x \cos x = 0 $$

$$\implies  1 + \cos^{2}x + 3 \sin x \cos x = 0 $$

So now it will be equal to

$$\implies \cos^{2}x + 3\sin x \cos x = -1 $$

$$\implies \cos^2x + 3 \cos x \sqrt{1- \cos^{2}x}= -1 $$

$$\implies \cos^2x + 1 = -3 \cos x \sqrt{1- \cos^{2}x}$$

By squaring both sides we obtain

$$(\cos^{2}x + 1)^{2} = 9 \cos^{2}x(1- \cos^{2}x)$$

but this is a quadratic equation in $\cos^2x$.  So , solve it trivially and try to find out the solution.

Comment: When you wrote $\sin x =\sqrt {1-\cos ^2 x} $ why do you take only positive values? it can give both positive and negative value. Isn't it?

Comment: @Math-Learner i didn't understand what you mean ? If square root give negative value then sin fuction also have negative value at same point. Offcourse underroot can give positive and negative value both based on values of sinx.

Comment: Your method gives $\cos x=\frac {\pm 1}{\sqrt 2}, frac {\pm 1}{\sqrt 5}$. The first two values gives $x=\frac {\pi} 4,\frac {7\pi}4,\frac {3\pi}4,\frac {5\pi}4$. Again similarly $\cos x=\frac {\pm 1} {\sqrt 5}$ will give another 4 values for $x$. So in total we get 8 values. But there are no option that gives $8$ to choose as answer.